# How to enable a keyboard shortcut

Tags: shortcuts-app

After creating a keyboard shortcut to use in applications, how do I enable it? I created one to show a "Save As" option in all apps, and one to show it in Numbers. I used the standard shortcut of <shift-option-command-S… >  but there is no little check box next to either one that allows me to turn them on. I tried closing Numbers and also tried closing Pages, but when I open them they are not showing a Save As option in the File drop-down menu.  I am using Mojave.

Comment: Save as… has an ellipsis. Three dots, which is not the same as three full stops [periods] Opt ; on an English keyboard, or copy paste. Apple Apps such as Pages & Numbers don't use the Save As command in the same way - though they do respond to the same default shortcut, Cmd/Shift/S, which [if you really insist] you can also replace for Duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I did use Opt; to create the ellipsis.  I was hoping a short cut on the menu would get around the awkwardness of using Shift-Option-Command S but, if I'm understanding you correctly, that's just not possible on Pages and Numbers. Good to know.